# Change color based on selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I want to make a kinda showcase design demo, where the user is presented with 3 dropdowns. I want the website to respond to what the user selects.

So in the first dropdown you are asked to select the color of the text(that includes all h1->h6, p elements, a elements).

The second dropdown is text-shadow(applied to h1->h6, p and a).

The third dropdown is for the font. I am loading in the font though fonts.google.com

When the user changes any of them the style should change immediately.

I have a jsfiddle my current code. That code sorta works, it changes color, stroke and font but only in it's own dropdown menu.

How can I get it to apply to the whole page?

https://jsfiddle.net/cajsw1eq/3/

```
<script>
function colorFunction(pos) {
   pos.className = pos[pos.selectedIndex].className;
   pos.blur();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the color codes in the option's id tags, like this, so you don't have to loop through all the different values of the options in the change function.

```
<option id="#FC6B0A" class="orange" value="1">Orange</option>
```

Then, you call the function when an option is selected. I would recommend putting the font, color and shadow in one function.

Now you have two options:

Use this function, with three parameters.

```
function change(colorId, shadow, font) {
    if (colorId != null) {
        //example of working code:
        document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.color = colorId;
    } 
    if (shadow != null {
        //code...
    }
    if (font != null) {
        //more code..
    }
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
 onchange="change(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id, null, null);"
```

Or, alternatively, you can call the function without using parameters, and get the values from within the function.

Comment: You can use the example code that changes the colors for the font and shadow properties. I don't want to do everything for you, because this is not my project :p and this already took quite a lot of time.